# PHP CLI "Out of memory" error on VPS server running CentOS with cPanel

Tags: php, symfony, centos, command-line-interface, cpanel

I'm running Symfony2.1 on a hosted virtual server running CentOS with cPanel. Everything runs fine except that I can no longer use Symfony CLI commands. I'm getting this:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 20185088) (tried to allocate 71 bytes)
```

error (for example when I try to run `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` or other useful Symfony commands).

I've used the same commands through the CLI for months without any problem until a few days ago when this error came out. I haven't been able to overcome this error since then.

I want to point out that this not a PHP memory_limit related error (see below), being an "Out of memory" error and not an "Allocated memory size" error.

The exact same commands run perfectly when added to a cron job (this is the temporary workaround I'm using now), meaning that the scripts themselves are not to be blamed.

## What I've tried to do so far:

- **Increase memory_limit in php.ini** (or directly on the command line) : as I suspected from the type of error I'm having, this had no effect
- **Search for any other php.ini file** that may overwrite this setting for the CLI : there was none
- **Monitoring memory usage** with free -m : there was plenty of memory available (which was expected, as the symfony commands run perfectly through cron jobs)
- Trying to find **if WHM/cPanel might have**, through an update for example, **set any memory restriction** for user accounts : I've found that this might be the case when using a jailed SSH shell (but thing is, I'm not, I'm using normal SSH shell), or if enabling Shell Fork Bomb protection (but no, this is disabled on my server)
- **Checking ulimit settings** on my server/account with ulimit -a : there are limits, but they amount to 256M whereas my "Out of memory" error indicated that no more than 20M seem to be allowed to PHP CLI
- Checking if there was any memory restriction somewhere in .conf files, especially in **/etc/security/limits.conf**: there was none
- **Checking for any other file that could set up that kind of memory restriction: this time I indeed found one, namely /usr/local/cpanel/etc/login_profile/limits.sh** which seem to set such limit (ulimit -n 100 -u 35 -m 20000 -d 20000 -s 8192 -c 20000 -v unlimited 2>/dev/null) => I thought I'd finally found the culprit, as the numbers (20000) seem to correspond, **but editing this file as root and logging again in my account through SSH had, again, no effect**

## My question :

I've now run out of options. I contacted my host but they are as clueless as I am (a lot more really, they don't even know about Symfony). Is there anyone out there who experienced the same problem?

If, by any chance, the `/usr/local/cpanel/etc/login_profile/limits.sh` have gotten me close to the answer, what I am missing? Do I need to reboot the server or restart cPanel, instead of just re-logging to my account?

On a side note, is this something that might-be related to a WHM/cPanel update (as stated, everything was working perfectly on the command line until a few days ago)?

Thanks for any help, and sorry for the long question.

PS: I've found other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but each of them was solved using one of the things I've already tried. So I guess I'm experiencing a different problem.

Comment: It really does sound like the script is using more than PHPs `memory_limit` allows.  Have you tried doing a `php --ini` to get the location of your CLI php.ini, setting `memory_limit = 512M` (or some other large number) then restarting apache?

Comment: +1 for well explained question

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did (making sure that it was indeed the CLI php.ini I was editing), but it didn't change anything. That is the reason why I seriously doubt it's a PHP memory_limit problem.

Comment: How many ram do you have in your server? Do you have any swap partition? I had some similar problem before using composer update in my vps and added a swap partition solved the issue,

Comment: Are you running ulimit -a as the same user you are trying to run the scripts as?

Comment: @Bruno-P Thanks, that's interesting. However I am able to run the scripts (as a cron job, they run), just not via SSH on the command line - and I've more available RAM than needed for the scripts (more than 400M)

Comment: @AliGangji Thanks. Yes, I made sure of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that following an unwanted cPanel update my SSH port was changed from the default value and I was unable to login. I restarted SSH in safe mode in order to login.

Today, on a hunch, I looked at the SSH port in `/etc/ssh/sshd-config`, restarted SSH in "normal" mode, and logged in with the correct port: the scripts now run perfectly.

So the cause was using SSH in safe mode, just that. Hopefully this very specific problem will be useful to someone else: never use SSH safe mode for daily use unless you absolutely need to.